# What is this pattern?

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics

I have a pattern of numbers from some simulation that I'm trying to piece backwards into some sort of formula. All I can see right now is that they maybe have to do with integrals? The numbers (which may be a decimal or so out, as this is approximated from simulation) and their associated values are:
$$2 - 125$$
$$3 - 142.6$$
$$4 - 166.7$$
$$5 - 200$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a general $n$, we have $n - \frac{1000}{10-n}$

See that $\frac{1000}{10-2}=\frac{1000}{8}=125$ for example.

Answer (score 0):

There are too few values here to say much, but there's a pretty good fit to 
$112.5 + 2.9 n^{2.116}$.

Answer (score 0):

Some patterns are

$f_1(n) = (n-2)(n-3)(n-4)(n-5) + \dfrac{1000}{10-n}$ and

$f_2(n) = g(n)\cdot (n-2)(n-3)(n-4)(n-5) + \dfrac{1000}{10-n} $ , where $g(n)$ is an arbitrary function over positive integers.

There are infinitely many patterns.